# COUNTROW() is ignoring the filter slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a measure as below, but it ignores the slicer filter. how to get around with this ? many thanks in advance.

```
measure = 

  CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS( 'df' )
                   , 'df'[column name] IN { "col1", "col2", "col3" }
        )
```

Comment: What filter? Which column is being sliced? How does this column relate to `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
measure = 

  CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS( 'df' ),
        FILTER(ALLSELECTED('df'[column name]) ,
        'df'[column name] IN { "col1", "col2", "col3" }
        ))
```